# Set camera constraints as if it were from solver

Tags: python, scripting, tracking

first of all: I am very new to Blender Python :-).

I performed a camera tracking on a video and I have now a camera with a MotionConstraints on it that moves accordingly. I am able to access the transformation matrices of the camera on each frame.

What I want to do now is to read these matrices from an external file and set them on the camera, as if it has been from the camera tracking solver. The problem is that these constraints are read only. How can I obtain this?

Thanks.